# Objective-C iOS parse string according to the definition

Tags: ios, objective-c, string, parsing

I want create an iOS app for my school.
This App will show Week schledule and when I tap on Cell with Subject, it will show me detail info about subject...

My problem:
Our teachers use shotcuts for their names, but I want show their full name... I created the file "ucitele.h" with definitions of their names, but I don't know, how to use it .

This is how that file looks:

```
//
//  ucitele.h
//

#define Li @"RNDr. Dan---vá"
#define He @"Mgr. Ja---hl"
#define Sm @"Ing. Mich---rek"
#define Ks @"Mgr. Svat---á"
```

I get the shortcut of Teacher from previous view from "**self.ucitel**" and I maybe want compare the contents of the "**self.ucitel**" with definitions and set the "**ucitelFull**" string from the definitions? I don't know how to say it .

when the content of the **self.ucitel** will be @"Sm", than I want parse "**ucitelFull**" as @"Ing. Mich---rek"

Answers in Objective-C only please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, sounds like your trying to **map** a short identifier to a full name:

```
-(NSString*)fullNameFromShortName:(NSString*)short {

    NSDictionary * names = @{@"Li" : @"RNDr. Dan---vá",
                             @"He" : @"Mgr. Ja---hl", ... };

    return [names objectForKey:short];
}
```

Use like:

```
self.ucitelFull = [self fullNameFromShortName:self.ucitel];
```

This is a dictionary that has the short name as a key and the full name as the value.

Some further suggestions:

- try using lowercase keys and comparing `lowercaseString`'s, incase the user doesn't enter the value with the correct case.
- You can move the dictionary definition into a json file and read it from your bundle, to eliminate the hardcoding

Comment: Another suggestion, use dispatch_once and a static NSDictionary to create the dictionary just once.